# clang not reporting floating point exceptions

Tags: c++, clang

I'm compiling the below code using Clang compiler in Windows and was expecting the floating point exception flag to be raised, but unfortunately it doesn't. Can somebody help me here

```
#include <cfenv>
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
 
int main()
{
    std::feclearexcept(FE_ALL_EXCEPT);
    std::cout <<  "1.0/0.0 = " << 1.0 / 0.0 << '\n';
    if (std::fetestexcept(FE_DIVBYZERO))
        std::cout << "division by zero reported\n";
    else
        std::cout << "division by zero not reported\n";
 
    std::feclearexcept(FE_ALL_EXCEPT);
    std::cout << "1.0/10.0 = " << 1.0 / 10.0 << '\n';
    if (std::fetestexcept(FE_INEXACT))
        std::cout << "inexact result reported\n";
    else
        std::cout << "inexact result not reported\n";
 
    std::feclearexcept(FE_ALL_EXCEPT);
    std::cout << "sqrt(-1) = " << std::sqrt(-1) << '\n';
    if (std::fetestexcept(FE_INVALID))
        std::cout << "invalid result reported\n";
    else
        std::cout << "invalid result not reported\n";
}
```

Output

```
1.0/0.0 = inf
division by zero not reported
1.0/10 = 0.1
inexact result reported
sqrt(-1) = nan
invalid result not reported
```

Comment: `-ffp-exception-behavior=strict` command line option, or `#pragma clang fp exceptions(strict)` pragma may help.

Comment: According to [manual](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html#id12), the default for the Floating Point Model is "precise", which sets `except_behavior` to "ignore".